# How to import python library from url in Brython

Tags: python, brython

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/python" src="https://cdn.jcubic.pl/StringIO.py"></script>
<script type="text/python">
f = StringIO()
</script>
```

(StringIO came from https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/StringIO.py with removed `__main__` because it get executed)

and got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'StringIO' is not defined
```

How can I import python library from URL? Is there a way?

**UPDATE** found it that in Python 3 and Brython `StringIO` is in `io` module but still I would like to know how to import module from url if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place it into server side **brython/Lib/site-packages** directory. It needs to be pure python naturally.

Also note, that you should be able to modify the sys.path search direcotries in  with **pythonpath** setting:

```
<body onload="brython(
        debug:1, 
        pythonpath:['http://example.com/brython/Lib/', 'http://e... ]
      )" 
>
```

So note that the paths are actually full URLs to module paths. It took some time to me figure it out as [documentation](https://www.brython.info/static_doc/en/options.html) (*currently now at 2018-03-20 brython-3.4.0*) does not give an example of that.

Also note that touching pythonpath value overwrites the defaults and you need to include them as well. In my understanding those are the current Apache PATH_INFO environment value, that is the current loaded path and the brython source tree Lib/site-packages.

Comment: I've used this `brython({debug: 1,pythonpath: ['https://rawgit.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/master/Lib/']});` but `from StringIO import StringIO` throw exception

Comment: Does it work before you pass/modify the pythonpath argument? See the [standard distribution](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/stdlib.html) I think it should be included there too.

Comment: the problem is that it search for StringIO.pyc.js file so I think it don't work with pure python modules

Comment: Not sure about that. There is io implementation in Lib folder.

Comment: this is CPython (some fork) https://rawgit.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/master/Lib/ and it have StringIO.py I expect it to load as python only implementation.

Comment: Actually, the problem is with the implementation of StringIO you are referencing. The implementation  is for Python 2 while Brython works only for Python 3 code...